# Installing Scapy on anaconda python 3. Windows 10-64

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, windows64

I am trying to install scapy on my anaconda. I am using windows 10. Everytime i try to install scapy for windows -64 it does not install. I install from the prompt. any other ideas, please :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to install scapy with `pip3`?

```
pip3 install scapy
```

Or you can try to install it like this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scapy
```

You need to check that you are installing it with the same python version than the one you are using

Comment: It work really well, ty so much, i am still a begginer :3

Answer (score 0):

1. Go To: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scapy
2. Click on 'Files' tab
3. Download Latest Package
4. Extract with '7zip' or other extractor software
5. Open 'Anaconda' Click on 'Environment' on Left side
6. Click on 'import'
7. Locate the extracted directory and open '.yml' file
8. Click on Anaconda->Environment -> 'update index'